# Java find duplicates based on conditions and overwrite/update partial data in the duplicate objects

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, data-structures, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet with the following sample data.

[image: data sample]

In Java, using jxl, I read the data into a custom object called MergeObject.java. This class is a simple POJO with column mappings to the headers in the spreadsheet. After reading the spreadsheet, I have an Arraylist of MergeObjects.

I don't want to use a Set because I want to retain the duplicates. I want to loop the List arraylist and find out the duplicates in the list.  In order to qualify as a duplicate, two entries need to have the same first name and last name. For example, rows 2,3,4 are duplicates, rows 5,6 are duplicates and rows 7,8 are duplicates. I have overridden the equals method to define this.

Here comes my problem. After identifying the duplicate set of rows (2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8), I will have a definition of which row is superior. For example, I might consider that the comment section that has "Normal comment" might be the superior duplicate. After determining that, I want to populate the "Duplicate ID" column of the "inferior duplicate" with it's ID value and then replace the ID column of the "inferior duplicate" with the "superior duplicate" row's ID.

So, row 4's Duplicate ID need to be populated with 82046555 and row 4's ID need to be replaced with 82046565. Rows 2,3 will not change at all.

What data structures do I need to use? I tried the below code but I am not able to get a hold of the duplicates in a list.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
               List<ArrayList<MergeObject>> superDuperList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MergeObject>>();
```

//Using JXL, in a loop, I have populated the rows into an arraylist called saoList.
List saoList = new ArrayList();

```
           ArrayList<MergeObject> innerList = new ArrayList<MergeObject>();

           MergeObject lastItem = null;

            for (MergeObject item : saoList) 
            {
                if(null == lastItem)
                {
                    innerList.add(item);
                    lastItem = item;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(item.equals(lastItem))
                    {
                        innerList.add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        superDuperList.add(innerList);
                        innerList = new ArrayList<MergeObject>();
                        innerList.add(item);
                        lastItem = item;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what `saoList` is here? I see you are looping through it but I don't see its declaration or assignment anywhere.

Comment: can you provide your complete code and did you try debugging your code and see why duplicates are not removed ?

Comment: @AmitK Yes, I tried debugging my code. First of all, I am not 100% sure if the data structure of Array of arrays is the right choice.

Comment: @YuChen. I didn't put the code here as I loop the spreadsheet and using JXL I populate the List<MergeObject> saoList = new ArrayList<MergeObject>();

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of your situation is Sorting.

Implementing Comparator interface on MergeObject will give you a sorted list. So all the duplicate elements will be grouped together. See if this helps you.